# Using Spring with Java 9+ and Oracle UCP

Tags: java, spring, oracle

When trying to use UCP in a Spring 5 application in Java 10, Spring throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: methods with same signature createConnectionBuilder() but incompatible return types: [interface oracle.ucp.jdbc.UCPConnectionBuilder, interface java.sql.ConnectionBuilder]
```

The class [`java.sql.ConnectionBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ConnectionBuilder.html) exists since Java 9, so my best guess is that running in JDK 9 or higher triggers some new Spring mechanism.

Is this a known bug or have I possibly misconfigured something? The same application works fine in JDK 8 by the way.

The full stacktrace can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/davidbilge/d4c134b1fc00b57369dcd6259b0a0178).

Answer (score 1):

Let's track it in https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17003 to see if it gets fixed.